# On the symbols for quotation marks

Tags: quotation

I want that each time that I write `"[text]"` on Latex, the compiler understand that the result should be `“[text]”`, not `”[text]”`.

In the same spirit, only when I write `'[text]'`, I would like to see `‘[text]’`, not `’[text]’`.

Consider that in my keyboards there is no `` ` `` button.

I don't like the `\command{text}` alternatives, in the same way that I don't like `\texit{text}`.

Comment: What keyboard localization are you using?

Comment: My keyboards are Italian. I also miss `~`

Comment: Install the Italian 142 keyboard (it is the one for programmers, it has the back tick and the tilde). See here: https://superuser.com/questions/667622/italian-keyboard-entering-tilde-and-backtick-characters-without-changin#. You can also type ALT+96 for ` and  ALT+126 for ~

Comment: Did you consider creating a custom command for that?

Comment: Welvome to TeX SX! What's the difference between what you'd like to have and what you obtain???

Comment: I think the `csquotes` pacakge should be able to help. This is assuming that you want to type quotes directly instead ``xxx''.

Comment: Are you on a Mac or a PC/Windows machine?

Comment: Italian 142, and any other custom keyboards, lack imputs for `{ }`

I don't like to use slashed commands and in some of my keyboards, there is no numeric keypad.

Comment: When I teach the LaTeX course, one of my first recommendations for choosing the set up is “buy keyboards with any layout, so long as it is international”. I guess that your text editor can help, though.